# Custom iPhone Alarm Visual Message

Tags: iphone, ios, siri, alarm

I'm looking for a way to use the built in iPhone alarm app, but I want it to display a customizable message when I wake up. I've heard of ways to make siri speak a message, but I want it to be purely visual on the screen.

Has anyone done this or know how to do it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the Clock app, click on the Alarm button and create or edit an alarm. The four settings are Repeat, Sound, Snooze, and Label. Type your desired text in Label and it will display when the alarm fires.